# convert hashMap to JSON response java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am using JAVA 7.
From HashMap>> data = new HashMap<>(); i am getting below Output
Here map contains dynamic records for days.
Here in array, first value is category1, second value is category2, third value is category3, fourth value is category4 .

```
{
  11/20/17={
    producer1=[
    ]
  },
  01/01/18={
    producer1=[
      1,    //category1
      1,    //category2
      1,    //category3
      1     //category4
    ],
    producer2=[
      5,
      1,
      9,
      1
    ]
  },
  01/08/18={
     producer2=[
      1,
      6,
      1,
      3
    ],   
  }
}
```

I want to produce output like below for all categories

```
{producerType : producer1
category1Data : [ 0,1,0]},  //  11/20/17 = 0,01/01/18 = 1,01/08/18 = 0 for category 1.
{producerType : producer2
category1Data : [ 0,5,1]},
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson API

```
ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
```

convert map to JSON String like

```
String jsonResp = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(hashMap);
```